# PHP SQLSRV has intermitent delay on sqlsrv_fetch_array/sqlsrv_fetch

Tags: php, performance, adodb, sqlsrv

we switched our DB connection from ADODB to SQLSRV and I seem to have issues with it causing intermitent delays using sqlsrv_fetch_array.

I do a query in my database that returns around 426 rows with 5 fields.

The code looks like this (for speed benchmark purposes I truly removed anything else it was doing) :

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $host, array("UID"=>$userName,"PWD"=>$password,"Database"=>$dbName,"QuotedId"=>false, "CharacterSet" =>"UTF-8");

$rsText=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sqlStr,array(),
                array(
                    "Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC
                ));

$row = array(1);
while(count($row) != 0){
    $row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($rsText,SQLSRV_FETCH_BOTH, SQLSRV_SCROLL_NEXT);
}
```

Running this with ADODB takes me around 50ms. Running it with sqlsrv will take me between 500-1000ms. The original query (sqlsrv_query) is actually faster with sqlsrv than ADODB, but there is random time delays with the sqlsrv_fetch_array (I actually tested with sqlsrv_fetch and also get them). I timed in ms every call to it, and while it's usually 0-1ms per call, sometimes it will be up to 15ms. Why I say that it's random is that if I rerun the code multiple times, the delays will not occur at the same place and will vary in numbers, so it is not because a particular row is large (which none of them are either way).

Does anyone have any idea on what I could look at that could be doing this, be it a parameter or configuration somewhere? I don't think it is server/network related seeing that ADODB never does this. We are using PHP 5.6 and the php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll / php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll and SQL Server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: How about different fetch and scrolling types? For example, leaving them with default parameters, what is the time interval? Looks like it's about some underhood operations in dll.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, changing the scrolling type worked! It seems that SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC was the problem. I tried all the options, and SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD gives the exact same speed as ADODB. You lose the ability to move first/backward, but that's not a big issue. SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED goes extremely fast, but has memory issues in some cases. All the other options that allow for moving forward and back have the same issue as SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC in terms of speed, so there must be something there.

If you want to write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: You can add your own answer because you tested them and you have better knowledge about this. I don't want to just copy-paste your comment :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by alalp in the comments, I tried modifying the scrolling type and it fixed the problem.

I did some quick benchmark and here is what I got:

**SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC, SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET and SQLSRV_CURSOR_DYNAMIC** : severe speed issue. As stated in the original post, looping over even a moderate number of records (few 100s) would take over a second.

**SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD** : no speed issue. Took about 50ms to loop through the records from my example, which was the same as ADODB. You lose the ability to do MoveFirst/MovePrev, but I think this is easily resolved by storing results in an array on your first pass if required, or depending on the query it might be fine to just rerun it in the rare cases where it is required.

**SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED** : blazing fast (0ms in my example, which makes sense because from my understanding it's basically the same as storing the entire thing in an array). We did have memory issues in some larger datasets though.

In our project, we ended up using SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED for the public website because no major dataset is ever extracted in one page, and SQLSRV_CURSOR_FORWARD for the backend where you can end up pulling 1000s of rows of data.

Comment: Even though this is a really old answer I find that I am running into the same problem. I am upgrading an old CI 2 app to PHP 7.4 and using Microsofts sqlsrv driver. CI defaults to SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC and one of our large queries takes almost 3 minutes when it used to take a couple of seconds. With SQLSRV_CURSOR_CLIENT_BUFFERED the speed is restored but it takes almost 2G of memory - much more than before. Not great choices!